# Given vector fields $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ and differential forms $a$, $b$ and $y$, find $\alpha(X)$...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, vector-fields

Attached is the image of the homework problem I am assigned.

I seriously have no idea  how to attempt the problem. Our professor is going very quickly over material and considering the lack of empathy he might have for his students, we are stuck on learning this material on our own.

[image: homework 1]

If someone could explain and show how to evaluate $\alpha(X)$, my buddies and I could probably learn from that example and attempt to do the rest.
[image: my attempt at alpha(X)]

Comment: Before you attempt to solve the problem do you know how $dx$ acts on $\frac{\partial}{\partial}$?

Comment: @happymath I was googling some stuff but couldn't make out anything useful.

Comment: I would suggest the book Geometry of Differential forms if you want to learn about this stuff. Anyways coming to your problem $dx$ is the dual of $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ that is it acts on this and gives out $1$ whereas on $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$ and  $\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$ it gives out $0$. Now you should be able to the question about evaluating $\alpha$ on a vector field for calculating $\beta$ you have to know how it acts and that is given in the book it is not complicated but too long for a comment if it is not long already

Comment: @happymath I'm still not seeing how to approach the problem. According to my notes we plug differentials forms into our vector fields, but the way to the problem is asked on the homework is we plug in vector fields into our differential forms.

Comment: I don't know where you saw that you plug differential forms into vector fields but the correct thing to do is to plug vector fields into differential forms because as I said differential forms are dual of vector fields and duals acts on elements to give elements of the base field. Hope this clarifies the confusion

Comment: @happymath so I'm assuming the new attached photograph on the main problem is incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56673/discussion-between-happymath-and-user338365).

Comment: I messaged you!